# Julia:passing argument to the `include("file.jl")`

Tags: parameter-passing, julia

I was wondering if it is possible to pass arguments to `include("file.jl")`. For example we parse the ARGS in the `file.jl` and use them in there. Similar to what we do in a command line by passing arguments.

Comment: Can I ask what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Imagine in a module I run several files using `include("....")`, and some of these need some arguments that I want to pass to. For example ideally something that semantically means `include("file1.jl", arg1, arg2)` and `file1.jl` uses these `arg1`, and `arg2`. for example imagine the values of these arguments are themselves created inside the module that calls `include()`.

Comment: In other words is there any other way to pass arguments to a file in another file/module other than using the command line argument passing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reassigning `ARGS` to make `file.jl` think it received arguments works, but leads to a warning (because it overwrites `Base.ARGS`). A better methods perhaps is to use `isdefined` to check for a different source of parameters before using `ARGS` in `file.jl`.

For example, file `main.jl` would be:

```
newARGS = String["adios","amigos"]
include("file.jl")
```

and `file.jl` would be:

```
localARGS = isdefined(:newARGS) ? newARGS : ARGS
@show localARGS
```

Now:

```
$ julia file.jl hello world
localARGS = String["hello","world"]

$ julia main.jl 
localARGS = String["adios","amigos"]
```

This also allows communicating deeper through several levels of inclusion.

Comment: Is there a way that does not reserve variable names?  In case someone in the future wants to `include("file.jl")`, but might have assigned the variable localARGS, perhaps when including a different file?

Answer (score 0):

To include code have the same effect than to copy that peace of code into the 'includer' code. If the included code run differently depending of several 'parameters' then that is probably a strong indication that you must encapsulate that code using functions or modules. Also, in julia, 'raw' code tend to be faster inside functions [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#Avoid-global-variables)