# Is there a way to run julia script with arguments from REPL?

Tags: julia

I can run julia script with arguments from Powershell as `> julia test.jl 'a' 'b'`. I can run a script from REPL with `include("test.jl")` but `include` accepts just one argument - the path to the script.

From playing around with `include` it seems that it runs a script as a code block with all the variables referencing the current(?) scope so if I explicitly redefine `ARGS` variable in REPL it catches on and displays corresponding script results:

```
>ARGS="c","d"
>include("test.jl") # prints its arguments in a loop
c
d
```

This however gives a warning for redefining `ARGS` and doesn't seem the intended way of doing that. Is there another way to run a script from REPL (or from another script) while stating its arguments explicitly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Julia:passing argument to the \`include("file.jl")\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967240/juliapassing-argument-to-the-includefile-jl)

Comment: If there is no intended way for such things then it is.

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't want to run a self-contained script by `include`ing it.  There are two options:

1. If the script isn't in your control and calling it from the command-line is the canonical interface, just call it in a separate Julia process.  `` run(`$JULIA_HOME/julia path/to/script.jl arg1 arg2`) ``.  See [running external commands](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/running-external-programs/) for more details.
2. If you have control over the script, it'd probably make more sense to split it up into two parts: a library-like file that just defines Julia functions (but doesn't run any analyses) and a command-line file that parses the arguments and calls the functions defined by the library.  Both command-line interface and the second script your writing now can `include` the library — or better yet make the library-like file a full-fledged [package](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/packages/).

Answer (score 2):

This solution is not clean or Julia style of doing things. But if you insist:

To avoid the warning when messing with `ARGS` use the original `ARGS` but mutate its contents. Like the following:

```
empty!(ARGS)
push!(ARGS,"argument1")
push!(ARGS,"argument2")

include("file.jl")
```

And this question is also a duplicate, or related to: [juliapassing-argument-to-the-includefile-jl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967240/juliapassing-argument-to-the-includefile-jl) as @AlexanderMorley pointed to.

Comment: I am under the impression that `clear!` is only a valid instruction on workers, and that attempting it in the main process will throw an error. (Not sure what is the rationale for this decision, but fair enough I guess). To "clear" the ARGS in this particular scenario, I would just `pop!` it until it's empty instead.

Comment: The right function for removing all elements of a vector is `empty!`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but it took me a while to figure this:

On your path "C:\Users\\.julia\config\" there may be a .jl file called startup.jl

**The trick is that not always Julia setup will create this.** So, if neither the directory nor the .jl file exists, create them.

Julia will treat this .jl file as a command list to be executed every time you run REPL. It is very handy in order to set the directory of your projects (i.e. C:\MyJuliaProject\MyJuliaScript.jl using cd("")) and frequent used libs (like using Pkg, using LinearAlgebra, etc)

I wanted to share this as I didn't find anyone explicit saying this directory might not exist in your Julia device's installation. It took me more than it should to figure this thing out.