# Isn't there any way to pass arguments in REPL mode?

Tags: julia

I couldn’t run my program from the REPL.
When I try this:

```
julia> ARGS = ["hello", "world"] include("test.jl")
error: ERROR: syntax: extra token "include" after end of expression
```

How can you make it 2 lines:
If I try to run first:

```
ARGS = ["hello", "world"] 
Error: ERROR: cannot assign variable Base.ARGS from module main
```

But command line is working without any problem

I tried:

```
julia> include("test.jl", ARGS = ["hello", "world"])
julia> include("test.jl","hello", "world")
```

none of them is working.

Comment: This seems a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015141/is-there-a-way-to-run-julia-script-with-arguments-from-repl

Comment: Correct. I think I missed that one.

Comment: But, I think  @Bill 's answer is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ARGS, the array of String command line arguments to Main loaded when Julia is run at the REPL is read-only. So you cannot re-assign it.

You can create a new module at the REPL and run your program via include in the namespace of the module, though, because Main.ARGS is not the same as another module's ARGS.

Let's say test.jl contains the single line

```
println(prod(ARGS))
```

and so then you may type this at the REPL command line (including use of the Enter key):

```
julia> module test
       ARGS=["hello", "world"]
       include("test.jl")
       end
```

The output should then be:

```
helloworld
Main.test
```